# Installing CVS on Scientific Linux

Tags: software-installation, scientific-linux, cvs

I'm interested in installing CVS on Scientific Linux.

I'm new to Linux and I need to input the command: "cvs co X"

My terminal states that what I have typed is an "invalid command," so I'm assuming that the problem is that I do not have CVS installed. After a lot of googling, I downloaded cvs-1.11.23, where the HTTP download link is provided [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/cvs.html).

I see that below the download link, there is a section written "Installation of CVS." I'm new to Linux, so I have little idea of the meaning behind these commands it says to type in, but I decide anyway to copy and paste them into terminal and see if they work.

(Naturally) just punching in:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --docdir=/usr/share/doc/cvs-1.11.23 &&
make
```

results in the following error message:

> "./configure: no such file or directory".

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'll admit I have very little comprehension of what this configure command is or how I should be using it.

Again my goal is simply installing CVS so that I can use the command "cvs co X".

Answer (score 1):

Scientific Linux is a Red Hat based distro. For these types of distros you can use the package management tool `yum` to install additional software from repositories that are maintained on the internet.

I would try this command to install CVS:

```
$ sudo yum install cvs
```

Any time you require a command that doesn't "just work" on a Unix system, specifically ones that are based on Red Hat distros like Scientific Linux, always remember that additional software likely needs to be installed.

#### Going further

If you need to locate missing software, `yum` can help you with this as well.

```
$ yum search cvs
$ yum info cvs
```

If you know only of a single command, but are unsure what package it's a part of :

```
$ repoquery -qf */cvs
```

Answer (score 1):

It is always better to use the software installer/manager that comes with the distribution. In the case of SL it should be "yum". Simply open the software manager and look for a package named cvs. It will take care of the entire installation process.